# Autofac MyLogger injection to MVC filters through AttachToComponentRegistration (Activated, Preparing)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm trying to inject IMyLogger to my filter class but without success. This is my code:

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
   public IMyLogger Logger { get; set; }

   public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { }
   public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }
}
```

Registering:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<MyLoggerModule>();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();

IContainer AutofacContainer = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(AutofacContainer));
```

MyLogger module is responsible for injecting MyLogger

```
public class MyLoggerModule : Autofac.Module
{
   protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
   {
      registration.Preparing += (object sender, PreparingEventArgs e) => {
        var type = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        /* using reflection check if there is a constructor with
           parameter of type IMyLogger and if so then create logger
           and setup in constructor
         */
      };
      registration.Activated += (s, e) => {
        var type = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        /* using reflection check if there is a property of type
           IMyLogger and if so then create logger and setup it
         */
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm debugging `Preparing` and `Activated` the variable `type` is never set to `MyActionFilterAttribute` and as a result of executing the `Logger` property in the attribute is always `null`

Is there any way to set the logger this way in filters?

If you want to try this here is Preparing and Activated full code:

```
private bool HasConstructorDependencyOnLogger(Type type)
{
  return type.GetConstructors()
    .Any(ctor => ctor.GetParameters()
    .Any(parameter => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IMyLogger)));
}

private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetLoggerProperties(Type type)
{
  return type.GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanWrite && 
     property.PropertyType == typeof(IMyLogger) && 
     property.GetSetMethod(true).IsPublic);
}

protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
{
  registration.Preparing += (object sender, PreparingEventArgs e) => {
    var type = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
    var hasDep = HasConstructorDependencyOnLogger(type);
    if (hasDep)
    {
      e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(
        new ResolvedParameter(
          (parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), 
          (p, i) => new MyLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)), 1));
    }
  };

  registration.Activated += (s, e) =>
  {
    var type = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
    var properties = GetLoggerProperties(type).ToList();
    if (properties.Count > 0)
    {
      var logger = new MyLogger(type);
      foreach (var prop in properties)
      {
        prop.SetValue(e.Instance, logger, BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, null, null);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

**------- UPDATE --------**

I've found one workaround to this issue. I've inherited from `AutofacFilterProvider` and overriden `GetFilters` methods. What I found in Autofac code was:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
  lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(filter.Instance);
```

this line just resolves instances and is not taking registered `Preparing` nor `Activated` calls.

My FiltersProvider looks like this:

```
public class MyAutofacFilterProvider : AutofacFilterProvider
{
  public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
  {
     var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor).ToList();
     var lifetimeScope = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope;

     if (lifetimeScope != null)
     {
       foreach (var filter in filters)
       {
         var actualProps = filter.Instance
                       .GetType()
                       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                       .Where(pi => pi.CanWrite && pi.PropertyType == typeof(IMyLogger))
                       .ToList();

         foreach (var actual in actualProps)
         {
           var setter = actual.GetSetMethod();
           if (setter != null)
           {
             setter.Invoke(filter.Instance, new[] { new MyLogger(filter.Instance.GetType()) });
             break;
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This solution looks fine but the logger in filers is not set every time. I can see the foreach to pass through set property but later in the filter is null.

One solution to this one was to set Logger property in filter `static` but this is not a perfect solution. Do you have any idea why Logger is not set every time in this case?

Answer (score 0):

try make your  **MyActionFilterAttribute**  implement  **IAutofacActionFilter**,
and put 
**builder.RegisterType().AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor().PropertiesAutowired()** 
into your autofact config file.

However MyActionFilterAttribute  no longer is an attribute